# DB2 - Using left join in a subquery

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, left-join

I managed to build a select that is working.

Now I need to JOIN to another table.

```
SELECT
    t.TICKETID -- the other table
    ,c.OWNERID 
    ,c.CREATEDATE
FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        *
      , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY c.OWNERID  ORDER BY c.CREATEDATE) AS RN_
      FROM  MAXIMO.COMMLOG c
      LEFT JOIN maximo.TICKET t  on t.TICKETUID  = c.OWNERID
      WHERE c.UNIQUEID = '468'
      AND c.OWNERID = '4355070'
    ) c
WHERE RN_ = 1
ORDER BY c.CREATEDATE DESC
```

Result without JOIN

| OWNERID | CREATEDATE |
| --- | --- |
| 16031985 | 22022-08-11-08.02.30.351000 |

Expected result with JOIN

| TICKETID | OWNERID | CREATEDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 16031985 | 2022-08-11-08.02.30.351000 |

Error for JOIN

`Error SQL [42601]: An unexpected token "." was found following "c".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.31.10`

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correlation names `t` and `c` of the subselect are not visible in the outer SELECT.
You reuse `c` in outer and this is why you can use this correlation name to qualify the columns there.
Try this.

```
SELECT
     c.TICKETID -- Here is the information from the other table
    ,c.OWNERID 
    ,c.CREATEDATE

FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        c.*
      , t.TICKETID
      , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY c.OWNERID  ORDER BY c.CREATEDATE) AS RN_
      FROM  MAXIMO.COMMLOG c
      left join maximo.TICKET t  on t.TICKETUID  = c.OWNERID -- here is my join
      WHERE c.UNIQUEID = '468'
      AND c.OWNERID = '4355070'
    ) c
WHERE RN_ = 1
ORDER BY c.CREATEDATE DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked perfectly for my scenario.